# Clarification of copyright in submissions to Wolfram Function Repository

Tags: wfr, copyright

The DATA repository has a statement [here](https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/submission-agreement)
but what about FUNCTIONS?

Does 3rd party  use include info about compiling the source into another language?

Note in particular this paragraph:

> Neither WRI nor any third party using your Submission in accordance with this agreement will be obligated to pay You any royalties or other compensation for use of your Submission.

Richard Fateman

Comment: **what about FUNCTIONS?** on  [WolframFunctionRepository.html](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WolframFunctionRepository.html) it says **The Wolfram Function Repository is a curated cloud repository** which tells me the same policy as data repository applies. But I am not a lawyer and do not even play one on TV, so may be someone who knows more would know for sure.

Comment: [This one](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/publisher/publisher-agreement) is the definitive license applicable to publishing functions in the WFR.